# tftpd-hpa installation failed in ubuntu software center

Tags: apt, software-installation, error-handling

[image]

the full error is here.

```
$sudo apt-get install tftpd-hpa

   [sudo] password for ashokkrishna: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
tftpd-hpa is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 581 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up muddleftpd (1.3.13.1-4.3ubuntu1) ...
Starting FTP server: *** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/bin/muddleftpd terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6998e)[0xb761a98e]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x6b)[0xb76ad37b]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xfb20a)[0xb76ac20a]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xfa8eb)[0xb76ab8eb]
/usr/bin/muddleftpd(shinfo_addtogrouplist+0x176)[0x805d156]
/usr/bin/muddleftpd(shinfo_setuparea+0x13c)[0x805d2cc]
/usr/bin/muddleftpd(shinfo_init+0xd4)[0x805d3a4]
/usr/bin/muddleftpd(ftpd_init+0x11b)[0x805af2b]
/usr/bin/muddleftpd(mainprog+0xec)[0x805b8ec]
/usr/bin/muddleftpd(main+0x18b)[0x804df9b]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb75caa83]
/usr/bin/muddleftpd[0x804dfc1]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0806d000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 422059     /usr/bin/muddleftpd
0806d000-0806e000 r--p 00024000 08:05 422059     /usr/bin/muddleftpd
0806e000-0806f000 rw-p 00025000 08:05 422059     /usr/bin/muddleftpd
09ea6000-09ec7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7417000-b7433000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360311    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7433000-b7434000 rw-p 0001b000 08:05 2360311    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b744f000-b754f000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 0          /SYSV2f132da6 (deleted)
b754f000-b755a000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360359    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
b755a000-b755b000 r--p 0000a000 08:05 2360359    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
b755b000-b755c000 rw-p 0000b000 08:05 2360359    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
b755c000-b7566000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360369    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
b7566000-b7567000 r--p 00009000 08:05 2360369    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
b7567000-b7568000 rw-p 0000a000 08:05 2360369    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
b7568000-b757d000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360353    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
b757d000-b757e000 r--p 00015000 08:05 2360353    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
b757e000-b757f000 rw-p 00016000 08:05 2360353    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
b757f000-b7581000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7581000-b7588000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360355    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
b7588000-b7589000 r--p 00006000 08:05 2360355    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
b7589000-b758a000 rw-p 00007000 08:05 2360355    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
b758a000-b758c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b758c000-b75a5000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360274    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1.0.0
b75a5000-b75a6000 r--p 00018000 08:05 2360274    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1.0.0
b75a6000-b75a7000 rw-p 00019000 08:05 2360274    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1.0.0
b75a7000-b75b1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b75b1000-b775a000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360284    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
b775a000-b775c000 r--p 001a9000 08:05 2360284    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
b775c000-b775d000 rw-p 001ab000 08:05 2360284    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
b775d000-b7760000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7760000-b7768000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360294    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.19.so
b7768000-b7769000 r--p 00008000 08:05 2360294    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.19.so
b7769000-b776a000 rw-p 00009000 08:05 2360294    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.19.so
b776a000-b7791000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7791000-b7794000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360301    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
b7794000-b7795000 r--p 00002000 08:05 2360301    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
b7795000-b7796000 rw-p 00003000 08:05 2360301    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
b7796000-b7797000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7797000-b77a4000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360376    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0.83.1
b77a4000-b77a5000 r--p 0000c000 08:05 2360376    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0.83.1
b77a5000-b77a6000 rw-p 0000d000 08:05 2360376    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0.83.1
b77a6000-b77aa000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360287    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2.24
b77aa000-b77ab000 r--p 00003000 08:05 2360287    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2.24
b77ab000-b77ac000 rw-p 00004000 08:05 2360287    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2.24
b77c6000-b77c7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b77c7000-b77c9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b77c9000-b77ca000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b77ca000-b77ea000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360260    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
b77ea000-b77eb000 r--p 0001f000 08:05 2360260    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
b77eb000-b77ec000 rw-p 00020000 08:05 2360260    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
bfe51000-bfe72000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
muddleftpd error in file ftpwho.c line 602: No parent pid in inetd mode.
CANNOT RESUME. Goodbye
invoke-rc.d: initscript muddleftpd, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package muddleftpd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 muddleftpd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ashokkrishna@ashokkrishna-Lenovo-B560:~$ sudo apt-get install language-pack-ia
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  language-pack-ia-base
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  language-pack-ia language-pack-ia-base
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 581 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 99.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 436 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main language-pack-ia-base all 1:14.04+20140410 [97.5 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main language-pack-ia all 1:14.04+20140410 [1,996 B]
Fetched 99.5 kB in 10s (9,204 B/s)                                             
Selecting previously unselected package language-pack-ia-base.
(Reading database ... 208113 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../language-pack-ia-base_1%3a14.04+20140410_all.deb ...
Unpacking language-pack-ia-base (1:14.04+20140410) ...
Selecting previously unselected package language-pack-ia.
Preparing to unpack .../language-pack-ia_1%3a14.04+20140410_all.deb ...
Unpacking language-pack-ia (1:14.04+20140410) ...
Processing triggers for software-center (13.10-0ubuntu4) ...
INFO:softwarecenter.db.update:no translation information in database needed
Setting up muddleftpd (1.3.13.1-4.3ubuntu1) ...
Starting FTP server: *** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/bin/muddleftpd terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6998e)[0xb757c98e]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x6b)[0xb760f37b]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xfb20a)[0xb760e20a]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xfa8eb)[0xb760d8eb]
/usr/bin/muddleftpd(shinfo_addtogrouplist+0x176)[0x805d156]
/usr/bin/muddleftpd(shinfo_setuparea+0x13c)[0x805d2cc]
/usr/bin/muddleftpd(shinfo_init+0xd4)[0x805d3a4]
/usr/bin/muddleftpd(ftpd_init+0x11b)[0x805af2b]
/usr/bin/muddleftpd(mainprog+0xec)[0x805b8ec]
/usr/bin/muddleftpd(main+0x18b)[0x804df9b]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb752ca83]
/usr/bin/muddleftpd[0x804dfc1]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0806d000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 422059     /usr/bin/muddleftpd
0806d000-0806e000 r--p 00024000 08:05 422059     /usr/bin/muddleftpd
0806e000-0806f000 rw-p 00025000 08:05 422059     /usr/bin/muddleftpd
08c77000-08c98000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7379000-b7395000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360311    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b7395000-b7396000 rw-p 0001b000 08:05 2360311    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b73b1000-b74b1000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 0          /SYSV2f132da6 (deleted)
b74b1000-b74bc000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360359    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
b74bc000-b74bd000 r--p 0000a000 08:05 2360359    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
b74bd000-b74be000 rw-p 0000b000 08:05 2360359    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
b74be000-b74c8000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360369    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
b74c8000-b74c9000 r--p 00009000 08:05 2360369    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
b74c9000-b74ca000 rw-p 0000a000 08:05 2360369    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
b74ca000-b74df000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360353    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
b74df000-b74e0000 r--p 00015000 08:05 2360353    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
b74e0000-b74e1000 rw-p 00016000 08:05 2360353    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
b74e1000-b74e3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b74e3000-b74ea000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360355    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
b74ea000-b74eb000 r--p 00006000 08:05 2360355    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
b74eb000-b74ec000 rw-p 00007000 08:05 2360355    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
b74ec000-b74ee000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b74ee000-b7507000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360274    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1.0.0
b7507000-b7508000 r--p 00018000 08:05 2360274    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1.0.0
b7508000-b7509000 rw-p 00019000 08:05 2360274    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1.0.0
b7509000-b7513000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7513000-b76bc000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360284    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
b76bc000-b76be000 r--p 001a9000 08:05 2360284    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
b76be000-b76bf000 rw-p 001ab000 08:05 2360284    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
b76bf000-b76c2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b76c2000-b76ca000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360294    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.19.so
b76ca000-b76cb000 r--p 00008000 08:05 2360294    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.19.so
b76cb000-b76cc000 rw-p 00009000 08:05 2360294    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.19.so
b76cc000-b76f3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b76f3000-b76f6000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360301    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
b76f6000-b76f7000 r--p 00002000 08:05 2360301    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
b76f7000-b76f8000 rw-p 00003000 08:05 2360301    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
b76f8000-b76f9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b76f9000-b7706000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360376    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0.83.1
b7706000-b7707000 r--p 0000c000 08:05 2360376    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0.83.1
b7707000-b7708000 rw-p 0000d000 08:05 2360376    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0.83.1
b7708000-b770c000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360287    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2.24
b770c000-b770d000 r--p 00003000 08:05 2360287    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2.24
b770d000-b770e000 rw-p 00004000 08:05 2360287    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2.24
b7728000-b7729000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7729000-b772b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b772b000-b772c000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b772c000-b774c000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 2360260    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
b774c000-b774d000 r--p 0001f000 08:05 2360260    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
b774d000-b774e000 rw-p 00020000 08:05 2360260    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
bfe80000-bfea1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
muddleftpd error in file ftpwho.c line 602: No parent pid in inetd mode.
CANNOT RESUME. Goodbye
invoke-rc.d: initscript muddleftpd, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package muddleftpd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up language-pack-ia (1:14.04+20140410) ...
Setting up language-pack-ia-base (1:14.04+20140410) ...
Generating locales...
  ia.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 muddleftpd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a language file issue as your error says..

Run this in the terminal, it will tell you what locales you have installed:

```
locale -a
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-in
```

and last:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Then run the installation again.

Or an easy way to check you installed languages is, open dash and search for "language support", just opening this will prompt you to fix any language pack issues.

Comment: to install the language-pack-in i tried sudo apt-get update then again iam getting the same error.

Comment: Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package language-pack-in

Comment: I edited this with any easy way to install the language packs, sould show up in a few mins

Comment: yes but i got this error i am updating it in my question.